# Output with the address of the files (Python)

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and I need help with a problem.
I need a code where I insert a folder that contains jpeg files and my output is the address of the location of all files contained in the folder.
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you look at `os.walk`, `string.join` and `string.endswith` as these are the methods you'll likely be using. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

os.system('cd //add your folder')
print(os.system('ls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 

def listJpegs(folder):
    jpegFiles = []
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        file_extension = file_extension.lower()
        if file_extension == ".jpeg" or file_extension == ".jpg":
            jpegFiles.append(os.path.join(folder, file))
    return jpegFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
I got it using the code below:

```
import os
path="folder example"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(dirs)
for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root,file)
```